# Why won't my villagers become unemployed?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I am building an iron farm on the realm I play with my friends. The farm wasn't spawning iron golems (it had when I built it in another world), so I decided to try relinking the workstations. I broke all of the fletching tables, and the villagers all are still fletchers, even though it is over 2,000 blocks from the nearest fletching table. What could I do to get them to become unemployed and then relink them? Also world version is Bedrock Edition 1.19.71 if it helps at all.

Comment: Have you traded with any of them (You can check by looking at their "experience" bar)? If so, they won't become unemployed, because trading with them locks in their trade.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Professions):

> Removal of a claimed job site block causes the owner to switch to another profession or become unemployed, provided that the villager has no prior trades with the player. If the villager has prior trades, it keeps its profession and claims a new job site block that matches its profession if one is available.

Answer (score -2):

Try employing them again, and then breaking the new workstation.

Comment: You're going to need a little more information than that, pal.